# this.router.navigate(['components/NewComponent']); is not working

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created new component in my project dashboard. the project path is like 
~src\app\layout\dashboard\components\New-Component

and i have added routing in my dashboard routing module like

```
import { NewComponentComponent } from './components/New Component/New-Component.component';
```

`{ path: 'components/New-Component', component : NewComponentComponent}`.

i have called this page from dashboard chart component.

```
onChartClick(e) {         
        this.router.navigate(['components/New-Component']);
    }
```

When i clicked on chart it is navigated to New component page but it displays same dashboard page.
http://localhost:4200/dashboard/components/New-Component .

Comment: is it mandatory to have a path: 'components/New-Component' like this? cant it be path: 'new-component'

Comment: i tried only with New-Component also. It behaves same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all of you for your help.

for this i have used `this.router.navigate(['../components/New-Component']);`

It is working now.

Answer (score -1):

add / before components

```
this.router.navigate(['/components/New-Component']);
```